# When Tcl starts an application process in the background via "exec ... &" can it be informed when that application is closed?

Tags: tcl

When Tcl open a process (another application) in the background, can Tcl be informed when that process is closed by the user? I tried the `bgerror` but a background error is not thrown when simply "x-out" of the application. Thank you.

Comment: `exec + &` returns the `pid` I don’t know your OS , but on Windows you can play with twapi package to see if your `pid` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with `exec ... &`, but you *can* if you instead use `open |...` and then detect when the pipeline is closed (with `fileevent` and so on). That uses the same underlying execution engine, but you take a bit more responsibility for handling some of the details.